# optimizing 2D-1D operation in python

Tags: python, numpy

What is the pythonic-CPUoptimized way to apply a simple operation like a multiplication:

- along one dimension of a 2D array
- to all elements of the other dimension of the 2D array
- according to elements in another 1D array

?

example:

```
x=np.arange(150).reshape([50,3])
y=np.arange(50)+10
```

I want to do:

```
np.array([x[i,:]*y[i] for i in range(50)])
```

but I would like to make it the quickest possible since the '50' could be zillions.

by the way is this completely equivalent to:

```
np.array([x[i,:]*j for i,j in enumerate(y)])
```

?

---

I made some updates here but finally opened a new questions

Comment: If you have a new question please ask a new question.

Comment: I will practise einsum (see 2de answer) and come back if I still have questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add a new axis to `y` using either `None` or `np.newaxis` so it can be broadcast across `x`:

```
x * y[:,None]
```

---

```
np.allclose((x * y[:,None]), np.array([x[i,:]*y[i] for i in range(50)]))
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, use the Swiss army knife of array products, that is
[`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```
In [9]: x=np.arange(150).reshape([50,3])
   ...: y=np.arange(50)+10
   ...: check=np.array([x[i,:]*y[i] for i in range(50)])
   ...: np.allclose(np.einsum('ji,j->ji', x, y),check)
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: You can do everything w/o `einsum`, you have just to find the right mix of transpositions, dummy axes and reshaping... I recommend that you experiment a little bit in the interpreter with small arrays to get a feeling of all the different possibilities.